# Starting .war file from another war in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, war

Is there a way to start/stop `.war` file from inside another `.war`?

I'm running SymmetricDS server using Tomcat 8 (it deploys it's own `.war`) and I need to start it, when a button is pressed and Stop likewise. Can I do that?

Comment: You can do this programmatically fairly easily - the Tomcat management interface can be accessed through the HTTP [using the API](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Supported_Manager_Commands).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a war file is "dropped" into Tomcat's `webapp` folder, by default Tomcat automatically deploys it and starts it. When source war file is deleted from the `webapp` folder, Tomcat automatically stops and undeploys the webapp.

So basically all you need to do is copy and delete the war file to/from the `webapp` folder to start/stop a webapplication.

Also (or if you can't do this) Tomcat has a built-in manager webapplication which is capable to deploy new applications (from war-files), or to stop and undeploy running web applications.
See [Manager App HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html) for more details on this.

If you want to do this from your code, check out the [`ManagerServlet`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/manager/ManagerServlet.html) class. You can call it with simple URLs and parameters. The javadoc of the class contains example URLs what you can do with it. Here are 2 important operations specifically to your needs:

- **`/start?path=/xxx`** - Start the web application attached to context path /xxx for this virtual host.
- **`/stop?path=/xxx`** - Stop the web application attached to context path /xxx for this virtual host.

Comment: Copying and deleteng seems a bit extreme, and as `war` is actually quite big -- very time consuming. You second option seems more applicable. I will check it out. Thanks!